# Debugging does not show right code path and values

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I wrote a code with pointers etc. When I tried to run it in a debug mode, it seems not to follow the right code path and does not let me step into a few functions. Also for the first time it encounters this statement for(unsigned int i=0; i

Comment: Your sources are likely out of synch with the generated execu...

Comment: did try cleaning and rebuilding, no use :(

Comment: I am not able to see values of all local variables. I tried changing the name of variable i to index, but when I add index to watch, it says   index CXX0017: Error: symbol "index" not found. The other reason maybe that it is not storing all the debugging information. How can I verify that?

Comment: try disabling optimizations. Some variables will be 'eliminated' by optimization

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check in your project properties under C/C++ > General for Debug Information Format, be sure it's set to what you need (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more info on debug info format)

Also check in Linker > Debugging if you have General Debug Info set to "Yes (/DEBUG)"